# Dial tcp addr:port: i/o timeout, EOF, and Connection reset by peer

Tags: go

Hi I have a simple server setup that intermittently errors out with the following errors.

> - dial tcp address:port: i/o timeout
> - EOF
> - connection reset by peer

Client code:

```
request, err := http.NewRequest("POST", "http://someaddress/abc?key=somekey", bytes.NewReader(value))
if err != nil {
    return
}
request.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
request.Header.Set("Content-Length", strconv.Itoa(len(value)))
request.Header.Set("Connection", "Keep-Alive")

response, err := client.Do(request)
if response != nil {
    io.Copy(ioutil.Discard, response.Body)
    response.Body.Close()
}
```

Server code:

```
func HandleMe(response http.ResponseWriter, request *http.Request) {
    query := request.URL.Query()

    key := query.Get("key")
    if key == "" {
        response.Write(nil)
        return
    }

    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(request.Body)
    if err != nil {
        response.Write(nil)
        return
    }

    index(key, string(body))
    response.Write(nil)
    return
}
```

The index function basically takes the request and adds to a buffered channel and returns immediately. The channel has capacity of 100000 entries for burst loads. Even during the peak times with burst load, the channel does not have more than 500 entries. On the other side of the channel are 20 workers which do additional processing for the data before adding the processed data to database.

Now the weird issue is that I get the 3 errors outlined above occasionally. The server processes gets around 30k requests per second at peak times. The three errors outlined above happen 2-3 times per minute, and in vast majority of the cases it's dial tcp address:port: i/o timeout issue. Does anyone happen to know what I'm doing wrong here?

Edit: 
Some stats on that server

> ss -s Total: 648 (kernel 0) TCP:   547 (estab 528, closed 1, orphaned
>   4, synrecv 0, timewait 0/0), ports 0
>
> Transport Total     IP        IPv6
>   *   0         -         - RAW   0         0         0 UDP   12        9         3 TCP   546       31        515 INET    558       40
>   518 FRAG    0         0         0
>
> netstat -ant | awk '{print $6}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -n
>         1 established)
>         1 Foreign
>         4 LAST_ACK
>        14 LISTEN
>        24 TIME_WAIT
>       234 SYN_RECV

Comment: The error describes what's happening, the Dial is timing out trying to connect to the server. Have you checked that the server can actually accept more connections?

Comment: I updated the original post with more information regarding the connection usage. I have tried ss multiple time but the number of total connection do not exceed 1.5k.

Comment: The SYN_RECV count looks strange. Either your server can't keep up with the requests, or a client is somehow not completing the TCP handshake. I'm guessing the former, but I wouldn't rule out crashing clients, network problems, etc.

Comment: BTW, you should check if `err != nil`, not the response in the client. There's no guarantee that the Body is not nil if there's an error. Also, there's no need for the `response.Write(nil)`

Comment: @JimB Thanks for the input. I actually do check for the err != nil but i didn't add it in the snipper since i wanted to highlight that body was being closed for client reuse. It definitely doesn't seem like it's the server since the resources are not maximized (the servers is using 5-10% CPU). In my test where I test the indexing aspect, I can generally get 80-90% CPU load without issues. I think it might be on the client side, so I will try to investigate bit more. Thanks!

Comment: If it is the server's problem, load had nothing to do with it. It has to do with how fast you are accepting connections. You generally shouldn't see much if any syn backlog, as the buffer is usually very small.

Comment: Thanks Jim. I'm assuming you on the server the SYN_RECV value is too high right? (sorry, I'm quite new to this so there is bit of a learning curve)

Comment: the backlog meaning. refer `http://veithen.github.io/2014/01/01/how-tcp-backlog-works-in-linux.html`