# Performance degradation with Go 1.5

Tags: go

For sometime now we have been thinking about switching to Go 1.5 for our production servers. Last time we tried, it was back when Go 1.5 was released but we saw major performance degradation with it so we decided to hold off on it. We decided to, once again, try Go 1.5 (1.5.2) and again, we saw the same performance degradation. Whenever we switch to Go 1.5, our timeouts increase significantly. The server handles around 30-40k requests/second with payload of around 2KB. The server basically unmarshals JSON payload -> reorganize the data into another struct -> marshals the data into JSON. The processing is pretty simple, but it's allocation heavy (requests + JSON un/marshalling). Here are the stats we saw when we deployed Go 1.5

[image: Number of requests]

[image: Timeouts]

EDIT: Both graph above represent average number of requests on the Y-Axis.

Is there something we are doing wrong when switching to Go 1.5? Or is the performance degradation expected? Or are there some setting we need to tweak with Go 1.5?

Comment: The graphs aren't very helpful without knowing what the Y-axis means, also see https://golang.org/doc/go1.5#performance for some notes about the performance in 1.5. The new GC trades some throughput for latency.

Comment: @nuss.justin: Sorry about that. I should have said they represent number of requests per second. The first graph is number of received requests per second, the second graph represent average number of timeouts per second.

Comment: Since you say your application is allocation heavy, and 1.5 is when the perf degraded, it's most likely related to the new GC. You can try making the GC a little less aggressive, something like `GOGC=400`. The GC stats are probably useful too, with `GODEBUG=gctrace=1`. Also check the GOMAXPROCS, since the default setting changed in go1.5. This topic would be more appropriate on the go mailing list (there's not really a programming related question here)

Comment: Totally plausible the write barriers and assists cause you more timeouts than the old pauses did. Other data that might help (here or on lists): what the timeout is, the old and new GC pause stats and latency histograms.

Comment: Two things you could play with: setting GOGC high and forcing STW GCs every so often with runtime.GC(), or trying many smaller processes.

Comment: Not that this answers the question directly, but if this code is at all related to the code in your previous question, it looks like you may have a lot of unnecessary allocations. Reducing the amount of garbage you create should help with your program's efficiency in general.

Comment: Thanks for the response guys.
@twotwotwo The timeout is 50ms (it's a time sensitive application). I will pull down more debug logs of GC pauses. I already have it for 1.4.2 but pulling down 1.5 is hard since we can't have such high timeouts in our production system but we don't have any ways to replicate the production traffic.

Comment: @JimB If you mean this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34093038/dial-tcp-addrport-i-o-timeout-eof-and-connection-reset-by-peer) then it's not the same code but it's similar. I will try to upload some code to give better insight.